# Why can't load CSS with jsdom module for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

In my local NodeJS app file I'm trying to load HTML file with CSS link using jsdom module and then display it on the browser this way

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
jsdom = require('jsdom');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
        return;
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf8'});

    var indexPageHTML = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
    var document = new jsdom.JSDOM(indexPageHTML,{resources: "usable"}).window.document;
    var indexPageHTML = '<!doctype html><html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>';

    res.end(indexPageHTML);

}).listen(80, 'localhost');
```

My **index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
Some text
</body>
</html>
```

But the CSS still isn't loaded and I still get the warning

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html: "http://localhost/style.css".

How should the `resources: "usable"` option work? Which is mentioned by the link https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom#basic-options

Comment: I think the problem is that you are writing head 'Content-Type': 'text/html;. And as node is backend it needs headers to get the text/css headers as well. Currently its thinking css file as html file. Try to add

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css; charset=utf8'});

Comment: @CreativeDip it was not me who down-voted your answer. So there is no reason to down-vote my question

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. Somebody else did, i feel that my answer is wrong so i removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to install the [serve-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static) module

And if we want to get the page with the same name as request url (for example get `another.html` when click by the link with `href="/another"`) it's enough to add

```
if(req.url != '/' && !~req.url.indexOf('.')) {
    req.url = req.url+'.html';
}
```

before the line

```
serve(req, res);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just because of your http server returns 404 error for `/favicon` url and same html page for every other request.
When you page loaded at first time in the browser, your browser parse `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` tag and send another request to your server. But your server returns same html page again, instead of styles.